# how to make a hql query for below scenario

Tags: hibernate

```
I am a beginner to hibernate....
I have a two tables like,

t_2013
id  name
1   donald


t_2014
id   name
2    charles

This is my jpa,


  @Entity
  @Table(name="t_2013")
  public class Test implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;
```

Here i create one jpa with table name of t_2013. My Question is how to get the data from t_2014 using same jpa. Is there any way to access single jpa to many tables with similar table structure

```
 Query
 -----
  List<Test> list=    hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession().createSQLQuery("Select * from t_2014").list();

error:java.lang.ClassCastException:

 or

 List<Object> list=    hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession().createSQLQuery("Select * from t_2014").list();

 if i use above code how to iterate it.

 Iterator ir=list.iterator();
 while (pairs.hasNext()) {
 Object[] pair = (Object[]) pairs.next();
 Test obj=(Test)pair[0];
 }
```

If i iterate above format i got this error : java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.model.Test. how to get data from similar table structure...

Answer (score 0):

You're not using HQL, but SQL. HQL uses entities, not tables. And `Test` is mapped to t_`2013`, not `t_2014`. Read the Hibernate documentation about HQL.

What you want is `select t from Test t`, which will return a `List<Test>` containing all the rows from `t_2013`. If you want rows from `t_2014`, then you need an entity mapped to `t_2014`.

Comment: i know it jb.. my need is how i get the data from similar table structure tables using single jpa.

Comment: You can't. Each table must be mapped to its own entity. Those two tables should probably be a single one, with a year column.

Comment: Ok JB, What you mention about the single one - I can't understand. Please, give an example.

Comment: I guess from the name of your tables that you have two tables that are exactly the same, one to store the data of 2013, adn one to store the data of 2014. If that's correct, then use a single table to store everything, and add a year column containing 2013 or 2014 to know if the row is a row of 2013 or a row of 2014.